# Job fails when using PulseSimulator: Job Status: job incurred error

Tags: programming, qiskit, simulation, openpulse

I'm trying to simulate a basic circuit using the `PulseSimulator` in Qiskit. The following Qiskit Pulse code works when I run it on the real device, but not when using the `PulseSimulator`.  The job monitor tells me `Job Status: job incurred error` and nothing else.

Trying to run any gates native to the device causes an issue. If I remove `schedule += inst_sched_map.get('u2', [qubit], P0=0.0, P1=np.pi)` then it runs fine, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I'd deeply appreciate any support. I'm using `qiskit 0.23.2`

```
#Essential Imports 
import numpy as np
# Qiskit Imports
from qiskit.providers.aer import PulseSimulator
from qiskit import IBMQ, assemble
from qiskit.tools.monitor import job_monitor
import qiskit.pulse as pulse

# Connect to an IBMQ Account and Backend
API_TOKEN = ''
IBMQ.save_account(API_TOKEN, overwrite=True)
IBMQ.load_account()
provider = IBMQ.get_provider()
backend = provider.get_backend("ibmq_armonk")
backend_pulse_simulator = PulseSimulator.from_backend(backend) #backend

# Get information about the backend
qubit = 0
backend_defaults = backend.defaults()
backend_properties = backend.properties()
qubit_frequency_updated = backend_properties.qubit_property(qubit, 'frequency')[0]
inst_sched_map = backend_defaults.instruction_schedule_map
measure_schedule = inst_sched_map.get('measure', qubits=[qubit])

# Assemble a job - circuit with a single qubit-> u2 gate -> measurement
num_shots_per_point = 1024
drive_chan = pulse.DriveChannel(qubit)
schedule = pulse.Schedule()
schedule += inst_sched_map.get('u2', [qubit], P0=0.0, P1=np.pi) # Removing this solves the issue - why?
schedule += measure_schedule << schedule.duration               
pulse_program = assemble(schedule, 
                        backend=backend_pulse_simulator, 
                        meas_level=2, meas_return="single",
                        shots=num_shots_per_point,
                        schedule_los=[{drive_chan: qubit_frequency_updated}])

# Run the job
job = backend_pulse_simulator.run(pulse_program)
job_monitor(job)
```

Comment: I've downgraded qiskit to version 0.23.1 and then 0.23.0. Neither version had any effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Job Status: job incurred error` with pulse can be the result of a timing problem in the execution of different pulses, but in your code the `PulseSimulator()` class must get backends provided by Terra such as `FakeArmonk()`, `FakeParis()`..etc. For example:

```
from qiskit.test.mock import FakeArmonk
backend=FakeArmonk()
backend_pulse_simulator = PulseSimulator.from_backend(backend) # using FakeArmonk() backend
print(type(backend_pulse_simulator))
```

The `FakeBackends()` have the properties of the IBM Quantum devices data and are stored in  Qiskit Terra.

Another way is to specify a `PulseSystemModel()` from a real backend and pass the system model to the execution method. Below is an example with `ibmq_armonk`.

```
from qiskit.providers.aer.pulse import PulseSystemModel
from qiskit.providers.aer import PulseSimulator

armonk_backend= provider.get_backend("ibmq_armonk")
armonk_model = PulseSystemModel.from_backend(armonk_backend)
backend_pulse_simulator=PulseSimulator()
job = backend_pulse_simulator.run(pulse_program, armonk_model)
```

hope this helps

Patrick